# Timeline Chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I am using a Timeline Chart in Google Sheets. Is it possible to make the number data in the chart show up in number format? For example, in the picture below, the number is 2175000. I would like it to display as 2,175,000. I have the data set up in number format already. It is showing up in number format when I test with other charts, just don't know how to get it to work with a timeline chart.

[Timeline Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn262.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try values suffix `#,##,###` under customize

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. I added the suffix, and it fixed the issue on the axis - it is now showing up in a number format. But now when I hover over a data point on the sheet, it comes up as 2175000#,##,###. Is there a way to fix this?